# How to check if a String is a valid int or double

Tags: java, string

I am trying to determine if a user's input contains a valid `int` or `double` instead of a valid `String`. If the input is an `int` or a `double` the program should state `"Invalid make"`.

Here is my code:

```
else if (tokens[0].equals("make"))
{
  if (!tokens[2].equals(String)) System.out.println("     Invalid make");
  // I have 5 spaces above because I don't know how to use printf with strings
  searchByMake(tokens[2]);
}
```

Edit: Sorry for the confusion guys.. "tokens[]" is an array of strings.

I am trying to get my program to print "Invalid Make" if the user inputs make = *number* (when *number* is `tokens[2]`)

Comment: Are you trying to test whether the string equals a specific integer, or any integer?

Comment: Depends very much on what you consider to be an int/double. Does `1.2345678+E9` qualify? Does `1.`? Does `.1`? Does `FF01`?

Comment: Any integer. It cannot equal a number because in my program a "make" is a name, not a number.

Comment: Please give more information about tokens array. Is it an array of String?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a function to test it by calling [`Double.parseDouble(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) and catching the [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) (this will handle `double` and `int` values) when it isn't like

```
public static boolean isNumber(String str) {
    try {
        double v = Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you could call it like

```
if (isNumber(tokens[2])) {
  System.out.println("     Invalid make");
}
```

And the `printf` with `String` might look like,

```
String msg = "Invalid make";
System.out.printf("     %s%n", msg);
```

Comment: This question is unbelievable. Correct answers get downvoted and wrong answers upvoted. Anyway +1 to you sir.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think people are only reading the headline.

Comment: need to add a second catch for null values catch(NullPointerException e){}

Comment: You could also apply the regex that is documented for the [`valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        try { 
            Integer.parseInt(s); 
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
            return false; 
        }
        // only got here if we didn't return false
        return true;
    }

public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    return isInteger(s);
}
```

and for double too..

Answer (score -2):

You can use `instanceof`

```
if(tokens[2] instanceof String) ....
else if(tokens[2] instanceof Double) ....
```

Comment: Because `tokens` is a `String` array. Your solution will never work.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen the OP says it could be an int/double. It could be anything. Moreover, I suspect its an array of `object`s.

Comment: Aah.. I get what you mean @RobbyCornelissen. But it would still compile even if its an array of String. The OP has not mentioned anything about the tokens array and hence you should reconsider your downvote.

Comment: @harsh.prasad It will indeed compile. OP specifies that he's dealing with user input. I will change my downvote if you can explain to me how OP gets a mixed array of `Integer`, `Double` and `String` from user input.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm really new to programming and had a friend help me write this program.. I'm just trying to finish it.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen User input does not mean something coming from command line. It does not mean its entered in some form. It means very little. We don't know how it was received, and then how it was parsed.

Comment: We split an array of strings into "tokens" in order to organize what exactly the operator (user) was trying to do with our program. for example make = Chevrolet will organize a list (this is what you don't see) in terms of that make. I am trying to have my program state "Invalid Make" if the user inputs make = 2 (or any other integer / double)

Comment: If he parsed `tokens[2]` as an `int`, why would he be asking the question?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen As I said, what if he parsed it as an `object`?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Um, how exactly do you plan to parse something as an `Object`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen serialization, pre 1.5 generics, poor coding, weird homework assignments, and the list goes on

Comment: The question was updated to state that it's an array of strings.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen for an array of String this will be redundant. I think we might have jump to conclusions too early. Maybe the inexperience crept in.. :p

Comment: @harsh.prasad If `tokens` is definitely a `String[]` it actually won't even compile.

Comment: @Radiodef no, it will still compile. It won't give an error. That is for sure.

Comment: @harsh.prasad Will **not** compile. *"Incompatible conditional operand types String and Double"*

Comment: @harsh.prasad You are wrong, it won't compile. `aString instanceof Double` is illegal. Go try it. Don't make me quote the JLS.